# Is there a function which satifies this condition?

Tags: functions

Is there a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which satisfies

$$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (f(x)^2-(2n+1)^2)=0$$

for all $x\in\Bbb R$? In other words, for all $x$, $f(x)$ is an odd integer.

Comment: what do you mean by "function"?

Comment: There's only one variable y

Comment: When I speak of "function", it is mostly in the simplistic sense without this infinite product. For example, sin(x) or f(x,y)=3y+2x=0. You see?

Comment: If I wanted to say it any other way, could you give me a simplistic function that gives me for any $x$ any odd number.

Comment: I have tried to make sense of your question. You can revert the edit if I have misintepreted it. But note that your attempt to put it in formal language didn't work very well at all $-$ you should just have asked, in English, if $f(x)$ can be an odd integer for all $x$.

Comment: ...And in any case, the constant function defined by $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ satisfies your condition. But it's not very interesting. So perhaps I did misinterpret your question?

Comment: Your statement "In other words, for all x, f(x)is an odd integer."  is incorrect.  A product is 0 is and only if at least **one** of the terms is 0.  Your product will be 0 if f(x) is odd for **any** integer.  As TonyK says, both of those conditions are satisfied by taking f(x) to be equal to a fixed odd integer for all x, in particular his example, f(x)= 1 for all x, works nicely.

Comment: @user247327: No. The product is $0$ if one of the terms is $0$, which is the case if and only if $f(x)$ is an odd integer. It is $n$ that varies, not $x$. (By the way, it was me that wrote the last sentence of the question, not Jotadiolyne.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ y = 1+2\lfloor x\rfloor. \tag{1}$$

Comment: Why so much complication ? $y=1$ is simpler. (The OP didn't say "non constant".)

Comment: @YvesDaoust The OP may not have expressed themselves as clearly as possible. The original question seemed to ask for **any** odd integer to be a value of the function.

Comment: No, I checked all edits.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Okay. Maybe not explicitly, but that is the way it seemed to me. I had to interpret it the way I read it, but obviously there is a lot of room for different interpretations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In a comment, the OP wrote "If I wanted to say it any other way, could you give me a simplistic function that gives me for any x any odd number. " and this reference to **any** odd number is what I wanted to produce in the simplest way possible.

Comment: Mh, $1$ is any odd number. The OP didn't say *every*, did he ? ;-) IMO, a more interesting challenge would be to produce all odd integers *in disorder*.

Answer (score 0):

Since the **only** condition the product imposes is that $f(x)$ must be an odd integer for each $x$, that means there are lots of such functions. Since no other conditions are imposed on $f$, you can pick any odd integer for $f(x)$ for any real $x$ independent of what you may chose for other arguments.

So any constant function with an odd integer as function value works, as does the solution by Somos. But you can also have a function where $f(0)=1, f(0.1)=999, f(0.2)=-3^{3^3}, f(0.3)=100!-1$, a.s.o.

What I'm trying to convey is that your condition in form of the infinite product is very weak. It means $f(x)$ must be an odd integer, but **nothing more**. $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ are not in any way related if $x_1 \neq x_2$.